# How to handle error from php handler file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, telegram

If there is an error in the js/send_to_telegram.php file, then the error script will work. How to do it?

```
jQuery("form").submit(function () {
        var form_data = jQuery(this).serialize();
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "js/send_to_telegram.php",
            data: form_data,
            success: function (result) {
                donemodal.style.display = "block";
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
                errormodal.style.display = "block";
            }
        });
    });
```

in js/send_to_telegram.php the following code:

```
$token = "5306003979:AAEPK2NhlxW";
$chat_id = "497358";
$txt = htmlspecialchars($_POST["text"]);

$sendToTelegram = fopen("https://api.telegram.org/bot{$token}/sendMessage?chat_id={$chat_id}&parse_mode=html&text={$txt}","r");
```

Now, even if you enter the wrong token in $sendToTelegram, it returns success. How to get error if token is wrong?

Comment: Telegram's API should be giving you the appropriate response.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The POST request is still going to get a status of 200 from PHP, even if there is an error in the PHP. So it will not `error`. You can send Error data back in the JSON, such that `result` has a status or something of that nature that helps indicate an Error from `fopen()`. Otherwise you have to have PHP respond to the request with a HTTP Error, like 404 or 500.

Comment: You might also consider using `curl` instead of `fopen`. Lot more options and better Error handling.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:** It doesn't use API response status code unless you tell him does that. What if we sent multiple HTTP requests and got different status codes? Which of them should be used?

**Solution:** This is what you need:

```
<?php

function post($url, $fields = []) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

    if (is_array($fields) && count($fields)) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($fields));
    }

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return json_decode($result);
}


$response = post("https://api.telegram.org/bot{$token}/sendMessage", [
    'chat_id' => $chat_id,
    'text' => $txt,
]);

if ($response->ok) {
    echo '{"message": "ok"}';
} else {
    http_response_code(500);
    echo '{"message": "Something went wrong"}';
}
```